# JPA with hibernate provider many-to-many fetch mode

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have 2 JPA entities User and Course:

```
@Entity
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Integer id;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name="UserCourse")
    private Set<Course> courses;

    // getters and setters
}

@Entity
@Cacheable
public class Course {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Integer id;

    // getters and setters
}
```

Course is cacheable. hibernate.max_fetch_depth is set to 0.

What I need is when I iterate through a user's courses, hibernate should fire a simple SELECT query to fetch courses from join-table UserCourse and load Course entity from L2 cache.
But instead, hibernate always seem to be firing a join-query between UserCourse and Course.

So the question is -
In case of ManyToMany association, is there a way to force hibernate to fire a simple non-join SELECT on join-table and fetch the related cacheable entity from L2 cache?

Comment: Have you tried forcing @Fetch(FetchMode.SELECT) on the @JoinTable field ?

Comment: You should probably make your association cachable.

Comment: @bhantol yes I already tried @Fetch(FetchMode.SELECT) but got same behavior

Comment: @JBNizet association between User and Course is transactional data that I cannot cache due to application requirements

Comment: FetchType.LAZY may help. This blog is about lazy loading components/associations but also accomplishes what you want. http://mrbool.com/how-to-work-with-hibernate-lazy-loading/26148

Comment: @bhantol the association is already lazy. A toMany association is lazy by default.

Comment: @JB Nizet Good point - Also noticed that the OP is saying this is occuring during course collection iteration.